# How to send the result of a select query to a message body of a mail in oracle 10G

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, oracle10g

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE STATUS_MAIL(FROM_MAIL IN VARCHAR2, TO_MAIL IN VARCHAR2)
is
  v_From      VARCHAR2(80) := FROM_MAIL;
  v_Recipient VARCHAR2(80) := TO_MAIL;
  v_Subject   VARCHAR2(80) := 'EMPLOYEE STATUS';
  v_Mail_Host VARCHAR2(30) := 'xx.xx.xxx.xxx';
  v_Mail_Conn utl_smtp.Connection;
  v_msg_body VARCHAR2(5000);
  v_output VARCHAR2(5000);

BEGIN 
 /*Result always returns 42 rows*/
 v_output := 'select empid,ename,mobile,dept from employee';
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_output into v_msg_body;

 v_Mail_Conn := utl_smtp.Open_Connection(v_Mail_Host, xx);
 utl_smtp.Helo(v_Mail_Conn, v_Mail_Host);
 utl_smtp.Mail(v_Mail_Conn, v_From);
 utl_smtp.Rcpt(v_Mail_Conn, v_Recipient);
 utl_smtp.Data(v_Mail_Conn,
   'Date: '   || to_char(sysdate, 'Dy, DD Mon YYYY hh24:mi:ss') || UTL_TCP.crlf ||
   'From: '   || v_From || UTL_TCP.crlf ||
   'Subject: '|| v_Subject || UTL_TCP.crlf ||
   'To: '     || v_Recipient || UTL_TCP.crlf ||
   UTL_TCP.crlf || v_msg_body );
 utl_smtp.Quit(v_mail_conn);
EXCEPTION
 WHEN utl_smtp.Transient_Error OR utl_smtp.Permanent_Error then
 raise_application_error(-20000, 'Unable to send mail: '||sqlerrm);
END;
```

Getting an error inconsistent datatypes 
@ EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_output into v_msg_body
while executing the above procedure, please help me....

Comment: You want to send all the records from `employee` table in `v_msg_body` variable?

Comment: Yes, above query returns only 42 rows and all have to be passed to the "v_msg_body" variable.

Answer (score 3):

So in fact your real question is: *"how do I aggregate multiple rows into a single string ?"*

The answer is to use [aggregate functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions003.htm). Oracle has introduced `listagg`-function in 11gR2 that solves this problem nicely but in earlier releases one has to do a bit more work.

When you know the right keywords Google finds a plenty of great resources, e.g.

- [String Aggregation Techniques](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php)
- [listagg function in 11g release 2](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=515)
- [the collect function in 10g](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=306)

I have collected the following examples from the above mentioned resources. Hope this gives you a good starting point:

**The table that will be queried:**

```
create table foo (d1 number, d2 varchar2(10));
insert all
into foo values(1, 'a')
into foo values(2, 'b')
into foo values(3, 'c')
select 1 from dual;
commit;
```

**Oracle 11gR2:**

```
declare
  v_str varchar2(32767);
begin
  select listagg('key = ' || d1 || ' value = ' || d2, chr(10))
  within group (order by d1)
    into v_str
    from foo;

  dbms_output.put_line(v_str);
exception
  when value_error then
    dbms_output.put_line('Exception: trying to insert too many characters to a varchar2 variable.');
end;
/
```

**Oracle 10g:**

```
create or replace type str_list_t as table of varchar2(32676);
/

create function to_string (
  nt_in        in str_list_t,
  delimiter_in in varchar2 default ','
) return varchar2 is
  v_idx pls_integer;
  v_str varchar2(32767);
  v_dlm varchar2(10);
begin
  v_idx := nt_in.first;
  while v_idx is not null loop
    v_str := v_str || v_dlm || nt_in(v_idx);
    v_dlm := delimiter_in;
    v_idx := nt_in.next(v_idx);
  end loop;

  return v_str;
end;
/

declare
  v_str varchar2(32676);
begin
  select to_string(cast(collect('key = ' || d1 || ' value = ' || d2) as str_list_t), chr(10))
    into v_str
    from foo;
  dbms_output.put_line(v_str);
exception
  when value_error then
    dbms_output.put_line('Exception: trying to insert too many characters to a varchar2 variable.');
end;
/
```

Note how I'll catch `value_error` exception that will be raised if the aggregated string won't fit into the reserved `varchar2` capacity.

**Output of both examples:**

```
key = 1 value = a
key = 2 value = b
key = 3 value = c
```